# Accessing Application Scoped Bean Causes NullPointerException

Tags: jsf

What is an Application Scoped Bean?  I understand it to be a bean which will exist for the life of the application, but that doesn't appear to be the correct interpretation.  I have an application which creates an application scoped bean on startup (eager=true) and then a session bean that tries to access the application scoped bean's objects (which are also application scoped).  But when I try to access the application scoped bean from the session scoped bean, I get a null pointer exception.  Here's excerpts from my code:

Application Scoped Bean:

```
    @ManagedBean(eager=true)
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class Bean1 implements Serializable{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L;
      protected ArrayList<App> apps;
      // construct apps so they are available for the session scoped bean
      // do time consuming stuff...
      // getters + setters
```

Session Scoped Bean:

```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class Bean2 implements Serializable{
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L;

     @Inject
     private Bean1 bean1;
     private ArrayList<App> apps = bean1.getApps();  // null pointer exception
```

What appears to be happening is, Bean1 is created, does it's stuff, then is destroyed before Bean2 can access it.  I was hoping using application scoped would keep Bean1 around until the container was shutdown, or the application was killed, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is correct:

> a bean which will exist for the life of the application.

However, you cannot access an injected resource in a constructor, as it may not be available yet. Your initialization line: `private ArrayList<App> apps = bean1.getApps();` is run during object construction.

Instead, access the resource in a method marked by a `@PostConstruct` annotation:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean2 implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L;

    @Inject
    private Bean1 bean1;
    private ArrayList<App> apps;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        apps = bean1.getApps();
    }
}
```